# Mikro-orm: Only abstract entities were discovered

Tags: javascript, node.js, mikro-orm

I'm working in a node.js (+Express) backend and I'm trying to use Mikro-orm without using Typescript.

I followed [this project](https://github.com/mikro-orm/express-js-example-app) as reference + Mikro-orm documentation but I keep getting this error:

```
MetadataError: Only abstract entities were discovered, maybe you forgot to use @Entity() decorator?
```

Is there a way to avoid using Typescript's decorators? Or maybe a better question would be is it possible to use Mikro-orm in a pure JS project?

The configuration file `mikro-orm.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  entities: [EntityX, EntitiyZ],
  type: 'mysql',
  dbName: 'example',
  highlighter: new SqlHighlighter(),
  debug: true
};
```

The versions I have installed are:

```
"@mikro-orm/core": "^4.5.10",
"@mikro-orm/mysql": "^4.5.10"
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please, provide your entities code, because issue related to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this exact problem when I discovered this question (thanks for posting).

I was able to resolve the issue by ensuring the default export from each of my entity files has the shape that Mikro-ORM seems to be expecting, which in your case would look something like:

```
export default {
    EntityX,
    schema,
    entity: EntityX
}
```

**EDIT

On second look I realize that you're using CommonJS syntax, so without seeing your entity files I'd assume you could be missing something like:

```
module.exports.EntityX = EntityX;
module.exports.entity = EntityX;
module.exports.schema = schema;
```

in your entity file, *or* you forgot to wire up the `entities/index.js` as shown in the example you linked.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I had solved this issue a while ago but for anyone having the same problem, I had indeed forgotten to wire up the index.js. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const appDataSource = {
  type: 'mysql',
  entities: [EntityX, EntityZ],
  dbName: 'yourDBName',
  port: 3307,
  highlighter: new SqlHighlighter(),
  debug: true
};

export default appDataSource as Options;
```

Comment: This works for me and if you need to read from env file then check the second solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `npm i @nestjs/config`.
Secondly, inside `appModule.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    ModuleX,
    ModuleY
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Thirdly, at the project Root create `env.development` put all env vars there.

Finally in `mikro-orm.config.ts`

```
const appDataSource = {
   entities: [EntityX, EntityY]
};


const configService = new ConfigService();
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development':
    Object.assign(appDataSource, {
      type: configService.get('MIKRO_ORM_TYPE'),
      dbName: configService.get('MIKRO_ORM_DB_NAME'),
      host: configService.get('MIKRO_ORM_HOST'),
      user: configService.get('MIKRO_ORM_USER'),
      password: configService.get('MIKRO_ORM_PASSWORD'),
      port: parseInt(configService.get('MIKRO_ORM_PORT')),
  });
 break;
}
//continue with the switch statement on diff environment
//if test env create .env.test at the project root

export default appDataSource as Options;
```

Comment: This is a second approach to read from env file based on diff env

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I was just about to fix that. 